# How do I create a new database?

Tags: database, applescript, osx-yosemite

Since upgrading to Yosemite 10.10.1, I can't create a new database

```
set theOutputFolder to choose folder with prompt "Please select an output folder:"
tell application "Database Events"
    make new database with properties {name:"Test", location:theOutputFolder}
end tell
```

It appears to result in database "Test" of application "Database Events", but it doesn't. It's not on my desktop, or at least I can't see it.  Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
set theOutputFolder to choose folder with prompt "Please select an output folder:"
tell application "Database Events"
    make new database with properties {name:"Test", location:theOutputFolder}
    save database "Test"
end tell
```

Add the save command to save your new database.  It will then be visible in Finder.

Comment: You may want to edit this to make it clearer that the @JMCA needs to include `save database "Test"`. If someone just skims the answer, they may not notice this addition.

Comment: The save command was the answer!  Thank you for your help, and apologies for not responding sooner.